# Sabre RedApp Implementation for JxBrowser

Tags: java, sabre, jxbrowser

I am looking for some help with the Sabre Development Kit to get an app that currently uses the standard default browser (IE) to switch to a JxBrowser, but I am not finding much in the way of Java examples of the use of JxBrowser as a plugin.  If you have any Java examples of how this is done would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Starting release 2.13.1, there are two types of browser that can be used in Red App: native browser and WebKit.

https://developer.sabre.com/files/Sabre_Red_App_Developer_Toolkit_Overview.pdf

WebKit browser is already based on JxBrowser.